# Dask computational graph optimization

Tags: python, dask

I'm really curious about how to optimize a computational graph. It seems like existing optimization does not have a functionality to rearrange the task to minimize the computation step. For example,

```
# small sample vector
a = da.array(np.linspace(1,10).reshape((-1,1)))
b = da.array(np.linspace(3,10).reshape((-1,1)))

c = da.dot(a,b.T)

ans1 = da.sum(c, axis=1)

# optimized way
sum_b = da.sum(b, axis=0)

ans2 = da.dot(a,sum_b.T)
```

From sample code above, we already know that `ans1` is equal to `ans2` and the time complexity is reduced from O(n^2) to O(n). From what I've checked, the optimize function do not provide swapping order of operation.

My question is, how can I achieve this optimization maybe in a form of function that pass dask computational graph as an argument or do we already have existing implementation for me to use.

Comment: I might be wrong, but this type of optimization is not possible with dask...

Comment: It's also hard to see the motivation from your example. Furthermore, in your case, a simple switch of operations won't work, since you also need to change the `axis` argument.